# Server Sent Events - How to Handle in Android

Tags: java, android, server-sent-events

I have created an application (following the current Android MVVM architecture using LiveData and Retrofit).  The app serves as a remote control for a lighting and entry access system.

I have constructed a Repository class that implements a network backend using Retrofit which makes calls to my REST API.  When I manually request (using GET) a status update I can get the status of my IO.  However, I need to consume server sent events for the same data on another URI for IO status updates.

It seems Retrofit does not support this functionality.  I have discovered other API's that seem to handle SSE like EventSource, EventSource-Android, OkHttp-EventSource, and Oksse.  Are all of these just different implementations of EventSource?  How are they functionally different from one another?

I learn from reading code written by other people; where can I find functional examples of how these are implemented?  My search results are not coming up with any useful examples.  Is there a recommended best practice for handling server sent events?

I really do not want to poll my server for updates, and I am confused why there is little support for SSE on Android.

For reference, here are some of the classes I have implemented so far.

Data Model:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root(name = "onboardGpio", strict = false)
public class OnboardGPIO
{
    @Element(name = "garageDoorFeedbackState")
    private String garageDoorState;

    @Element(name = "zoneOneState")
    private String zoneOneState;

    @Element(name = "zoneTwoState")
    private String zoneTwoState;

    @Element(name = "zoneThreeState")
    private String zoneThreeState;

    @Element(name = "systemArmedState")
    private String systemArmed;

    @Element(name = "panelTemperature")
    private String panelTemperature;

    @Element(name = "garageDoorRelayState")
    private String garageDoorRelayState;

    @Element(name = "zoneOneRelayState")
    private String zoneOneRelayState;

    @Element(name = "zoneTwoRelayState")
    private String zoneTwoRelayState;

    @Element(name = "zoneThreeRelayState")
    private String zoneThreeRelayState;

    ...getters & setters...
}
```

Repository Class

```
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData;
import ca.thirdgear.homeautomation.http.HomeAutomationAPI;
import ca.thirdgear.homeautomation.http.HomeAutomationController;
import ca.thirdgear.homeautomation.model.OnboardGPIO;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class DataRepository
{
    private static DataRepository dataRepository;
    private HomeAutomationController homeAutomationController;
    private HomeAutomationAPI homeAutomationAPIService;
    private MutableLiveData<String> zoneOneState;
    private MutableLiveData<String> zoneTwoState;
    private MutableLiveData<String> garageDoorState;

    public static DataRepository getInstance()
    {
        if(dataRepository == null)
        {
            dataRepository = new DataRepository();
        }
        return dataRepository;
    }

    private DataRepository()
    {
        homeAutomationController = HomeAutomationController.getInstance();
        homeAutomationAPIService = homeAutomationController.createService(HomeAutomationAPI.class);
        zoneOneState = new MutableLiveData<>();
        zoneTwoState = new MutableLiveData<>();
        garageDoorState = new MutableLiveData<>();
    }

    //get status of remote API I/O
    public void getIoStatus()
    {
        Call<OnboardGPIO> call = homeAutomationAPIService.getIoStatus();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<OnboardGPIO>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<OnboardGPIO> call, Response<OnboardGPIO> response)
            {
                if(response.isSuccessful())
                {
                    zoneOneState.setValue(response.body().getZoneOneState());
                    zoneTwoState.setValue(response.body().getZoneTwoState());
              garageDoorState.setValue(response.body().getGarageDoorState());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<OnboardGPIO> call, Throwable t)
            {
                //TODO
            }
        });

        ... other network calls ...
}
```

Network class

```
import okhttp3.Credentials;
import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.simplexml.SimpleXmlConverterFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HomeAutomationController
{
    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://MY_URL/";
    private static HomeAutomationController homeAutomationController;
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    public static HomeAutomationController getInstance()
    {
        if(homeAutomationController == null)
        {
            homeAutomationController = new HomeAutomationController();
        }
        return homeAutomationController;
    }

    private HomeAutomationController()
    {
        //create OkHttpClient
        okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();

            Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("Authorization",
                    Credentials.basic("USERNAME", "PASSWORD"));

            Request newRequest = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
            }
        })
            .readTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

        //create retrofit object
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(SimpleXmlConverterFactory.create())
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
    }

    //create and return http service
    public <S> S createService(Class <S> serviceClass)
    {
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }

}
```

Comment: There are two ways you can get updates from server. 1: User firebase server and use firebase messaging. 2. Make a service which will run forever in the background and check fro any change in the online db. If you want an example of the 2nd type I can help you with it.

Comment: Thanks.  I am not familiar with Firebase and will need to read up on it.  What does the background service you mention involve?

Comment: It seems related with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032031/how-to-use-server-sent-events-sse-in-android

Comment: I've read that question, and admit it is similar, but that question, and a lot related to SSE seem to be several years old.  I know there are API's available, but I can not find may reference examples to see how other people handle SSE.

Comment: For an IoT project, I think you should go with mqtt: http://mqtt.org/. Though there are so many things you need to build.

Comment: I have a REST server already running (Dropwizard).  I simply need to consume the events being produced.

Comment: `I've read that question, and admit it is similar, but that question, and a lot related to SSE seem to be several years old. I know there are API's available, but I can not find may reference examples to see how other people handle SSE.` Sorry for that, I haven't get my hands on SSE. For the Firebase part, you should not use it for home automation project. There is no guarantee that your message is sent. It's a very-soft real-time messaging.

Comment: Yeah mqtt is one of the best options for IOT projects. That is the best recommended. But still if you want to do it using the REST api then have a look at the [link](https://github.com/NeilSayok/GPS-Car-Locator-System/blob/master/CarLocatorUserSide1M/app/src/main/java/com/example/neil/carlocatoruserside1m/getLocationService.java). Here I have used volley and a Runnable-Handler and it checks the db every 3 secs.

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at this.